# How does hyperquest (a nodejs module) work?

Tags: node.js, express

When I was using `request` module, streaming in production environment was very brittle. Changing the module to `hyperquest` fixed the issue like magic wand.

I have read the readme of [hyperquest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyperquest). But unable to find the HOW part. 
The source code is using module "through2" and "duplexer2". But I am unable to understand it.

If someone familiar with these modules can help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

I have no code evidence for this, only anecdotal experience from conversations with other developers who have implemented request style libraries due to the brittle nature of `request`.

As I understand it, `request` only handles piping of streams within the same tick. After the tick has passed, `request` does it's 'magic' by modifying the stream (e.g. forcing uncork on the stream), and this breaks streaming compatibility. `hyperquest` is designed to be used purely for the purpose of http streaming, and does not contain all the helper functionality of `request`, so it avoids breaking compatibility.